# Are Hadoop and Map/Reduce useful for BIG parallel processes?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I have a superficial understanding of Hadoop and Map/Reduce. I see it can be useful for running many instances of small independent processes. But can I use this infrastructure (with its fault tolerance, scalability and ease of use) to run BIG independent processes?

Let's say I want to run certain analysis of the status of the clients of my company (600), and this analysis requires about 1 min of process, accessing a variety of static data, but the analysis of one client is not related to the others. So now I have 10 hs of centralized processing, but if I can distribute this processing in 20 nodes, I can expect to finish it in about half hour (plus some overhead due to replication of data). And if I can rent 100 nodes in Amazon EC2 for an affordable price, it will be done in about 6 minutes and that will change radically the usability of my analysis.

Is Hadoop the right tool to solve my problem? Can it run big Mapper processes that take 1 min each? If not, where should I look?

Thanks in advance.